# Using a class within another classes Constructor, C#

Tags: c#, class, constructor, console-application

so I am slowly reading through the book "The C# players guide, second edition." and I have gotten to a Try it Out! activity involving classes. It tells me to create a Color class with getters and setters for red, blue, green and alpha, which I have done.

It also told me to make a ball class, which will require size, Color (using the color class) and timesThrown variables. I have done that fine and I am now back in  the main Program class making instances of the ball class.

Really I am just curious as to what is a better way to go about making this ball because one way looks more efficient, but then I am not sure how to use the getters and setters of the Color class, and the other way looks less efficient but allows me to use all of that. And without being able to use the methods in the class I don't see why i wouldn't just define the colors within the Ball class anyway, unless just for the sake of learning about classes and how to make them, this tutorial has had me do it this way?

So the way I personally did it first, which let me use all the methods in the Color class was like so:

```
Color red_color = new Color(255, 0, 0);
Ball red_ball = new Ball(5, red_color);
```

because that lets me do red_color.GetRed(); for example.

The other way is this:

```
Ball blue_ball = new Ball(4, new Color(0, 0, 255));
```

However when I do this way, how am I supposed to use the methods defined within the class Color? My first instinct was to use Static as I am not making a instance, but obviously for example, red, isn't always going to be the same value for each ball so that wouldn't work.

So yeah, does the second approach allow to me use the Colors methods at all? Apologies if I worded myself poorly.

Comment: why would red not always be the same for each ball? the code should be the same shouldn't it?

Comment: I'm confused - are you saying you want to use the color passed to the `Ball` constructor _outside_ of that class?  Then either expose the color as a property of `Ball` or use a local variable.  If you're wanting to use it _inside_ the `Ball` class then show what you're wanting to do but can't.

Comment: Also tutorials aren't _perfect_ - they're designed to give you an understanding of _specific concepts_ and may not be good _real-world_ designs. Perhaps a _later_ tutorial exposed the color as a property and you just haven't gotten there yet?

Answer (score 0):

> My first instinct was to use Static as I am not making a instance

Well you're making an instance. **Every time you see a new keyword that's a new instance**. You just don't have a reference for it as you passed it directly to the constructor:

new Ball(4, **new Color(0, 0, 255)**);

If you have a `public BallColor Color { set; get; }` inside the `Ball` class then Color is accessible through the `Ball` object like this :

`red_ball.BallColor.Something`

So, if you just need the `Color` object to pass it to the constructor of `Ball` , use the second method. If you need a reference to `Color` in order to read/write data to/from that object in the code that follows in your program, then use the first approach.

There is no rule here, it is based on the code that follows and the usage. So you need to ask yourself :

*Do I need to keep a reference to the Color object outside my Ball object ?*

Answer (score 0):

In your ball class you can add a property called color like this

```
Color BallColor {get;private set;}
```

and in your constructor you should set the ball color you want

```
Ball blue_ball = new Ball(4, new Color(0, 0, 255));
```

and the you can use the color methods like this

```
blue_ball.BallColor.GetRed();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only place you'll need to interact with that instance of `Color` is inside that instance of `Ball`, do it the second way.

However, if you'll need to interact with that instance of `Color` someplace else, do it the first way. For example, if you're creating four red `Ball`s in a row, create one red `Color` instance and pass it to each of them:

```
var balls = new List<Ball>();
var red = new Color(255, 0, 0);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    balls.Add(new Ball(4, red));
}
```

Sometimes one is appropriate, sometimes the other. Neither is absolutely "best"; do what works in the specific case you've got in front of you. Sometimes you might create a local variable just to aid readability.

See @ShlomiHaver's answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can do this, but remember that the context of an instantiated object is always the most important thing.

You want to know the color of the ball, right? So add a suitable method to the Ball class.

```
public class Ball
{
    private int Size { get; set; }
    private Color BallColor { get; set;}

    Ball(int size, Color color)
    {
        Size = size;
        BallColor = color;
    }

    public Color GetBallColor()
    {
        return BallColor;
    }
}
```

Then you can use the ball's color like this:

```
var ball = new Ball(5, new Color(0, 0, 0));
var ballColor = ball.GetBallColor();
var ballColorRedValue = ballColor.GetRed();
```

Achieving the same thing using properties is absolutely acceptable.